# How to make for loop jump 4 steps

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to make a for loop in php that goes like this

```
for($x=1; $x<=100; $x+4)
```

so it the outprint will be like this 1 4 8 12 etc

this code is not working, thats why im asking for help :)

Comment: *code is not working* What does that mean? Do you get: `PHP warning: code is not working on line 4` ?

Comment: You can't get the output `1 4 8 12...` by jumping 4 steps each time, because you are starting at 1, not 0.  Note that 1+4 is 5, not 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for($x=1; $x<=100;$x+=4)
```

Change your last expr to be `$x+=4`
The problem with your code is that $x is not being incremented.

Comment: There is a small problem.. This will output 1, 5, 9. If you initialize to `0`, it will go 0, 4, 8, ..

Comment: Dedee, I had to wait abit :) its done now. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: bijan: its not a problem, I start from 1, just change the value to 0 if you want to start from there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to increment in terms of 1 4 8 12 ... you could try this code which is a little bit unconventional since you want to include when $x=1

```
for($x=1;$x<100;$x++) {
     if($x %4 != 0 && $x != 1) continue;
     else enter code here
}
```